# Can I use Organization, NewsArticle and Service Schema.org itemscope on one page?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I've been looking around on **Schema.org** but I don't find any information about this. Can a single HTML page be made up of multiple schemas?

We have a page Article/Service page we are working on. I would like to have the following Schemas in place on it:

- Organization
- News Article
- Service

I think the organization and News Article doesn't have problem, but what about "News Article" and "Service"?

Google testing tool doesn't show me errors, actually detect the three elements

Comment: How are these three items related to each other?

Comment: you mean, code?

Comment: No, semantically. For example: 
Is the organization the publisher or the topic of the news article? Is the service an advertisement or the topic of the news article, or does the org. provide the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guide of Google **[Follow the structured data guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies)** tells us:

> **Important: Google does not guarantee that your structured data will show up in search results**, even if your page is marked up correctly
>   according to the Structured Data Testing Tool. Here are some common
>   reasons why:
>   ...The structured data **is not representative of the main content of
>   the page**...

and further:

> Relevance
>
> Your structured data should be a true representation of the page
>   content.

In your poster, you report about the top level type such as **[NewsArticle](https://schema.org/NewsArticle)**. This type has the property **[publisher](https://schema.org/publisher)** with the ability to create nested markup for the type **Organization**. Thus, you can specify all the data for your organization inside the top level type NewsArticle. This same property **[recommends using Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article#article_types)** (however, only for amp web pages, and this is not entirely clear).

The specification of this type tells us:

> A NewsArticle is an article whose content reports news, or provides
>   background context and supporting materials for understanding the
>   news.

In this way, we can understand that your potential web page has content such as news. However, I can not imagine that some kind of news can provide some kind of services. This does not make sense, so the type Service for a news article can hardly be useful and relevant.

General note: each webpage is a document and, like any document, a webpage has a subject of content. Probably this subject should be the top-level type (main type) in your structured data. No document can have more than one subject. Many separate types of structured data for a web page will compete and divide the juice among themselves, and perhaps this will be simply ignored by search engines and your work with the data will be wasted.

Check my answer to a similar question **[Can I duplicate product schema markup on my home page because Google is preferring to rank my home page for product terms?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/121882/can-i-duplicate-product-schema-markup-on-my-home-page-because-google-is-preferri/121904#121904)**